# Can I split a SATA data connection at the hard drive end?

Tags: hard-drive, sata

I've seen one other post about this but my use case is a bit different. I'd like to use one hard drive on 2 different machines, only accessing the drive with one at a time (they won't be powered on at the same time) and I'd like to able to do this without unplugging anything. Does a splitter, selector/switch, or any other kind of hardware exist that with achieve this and, if not, can I make it myself?

Comment: “Does a splitter, selector/switch, or any other kind of hardware exist that with achieve this and, if not, can I make it myself?” - What you describe does NOT exist

Comment: Connecting it to two independent power supplies is a recipe for short circuits, destroyed PCs, and house fires. Russian roulette is probably safer.

Answer (score 1):

[They make a hot-swappable hard drive bay (usually fits in 5.25" CDROM spot)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B073JJ2FVR), thats likely the recommended solution. People typically just use a USB or eSATA drive for this need. Splitting a SATA cable between two PC's sounds like a bad idea electrically & data-safety-wise